# Retrieve values using Sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, store

I'm new to Android and I don't know how to retrive the values stored using sharedpreferences, I couldn't find any example of what I have to write on the other activity to use these values. If someone can help me I would really appreciate it

This is how I am storing the data:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
    String restoredText1 = prefs.getString("cpw", "30");
    if (restoredText1 != null) {
        savedcostperworker.setText(restoredText1, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
        int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
        if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
            savedcostperworker.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
    editor.putString("cpw", savedcostperworker.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("selection-start", savedcostperworker.getSelectionStart());
    editor.putInt("selection-end", savedcostperworker.getSelectionEnd());
}

private EditText savedcostperworker;
```

Now I want to show the value "cpw" in a TextView in another activity, but I don't know how

Comment: You missing editor.commit() after putting values in editor.putInt().. which is must needed,otherwise the edits will not be put into the prefs file.To get this value on other activity you need to use getSharedPreferences()..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to call [`commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) to save your Editor changes:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
...
editor.commit();
```

---

> Now I want to show the value "cpw" in a TextView in another activity, but I don't know how

Simply call `getSharedPreferences()` with the first Activity's name and use it like before:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MainActivity", 0);
String string = prefs.getString("cpw", "String not found");
Log.v("SharedPrefs", string);
```

You cannot use `getPreferences()` in the second Activity because it will call `getSharedPreferences()` with the wrong file name. See [`getPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thank you!! It works! I've wasted so much time looking for the solution and now it seems so easy